# Pass form vars to Google Maps API for origin and destination

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion

I have a regular form (not JS) that has one input that pulls a list of cities up from the db and another that has hard-wired airport locations.

I need to pass these two locations to the Google Map API to return distance and driving directions.

Here is the demo code for the API interaction:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

I'm also open to using this Coldfusion component, but spun my wheels for hours trying to get it to play nice with this regular form without success.

http://cfgmap.riaforge.org/

Any help much appreciated.

The form:

```
 <form name="frmAutoCompleteCountry" id="frmAutoCompleteCountry" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Select the airport:

 <select name="airport">
   <option value="sfo">San Francisco Airport</option>
   <option value="oak">Oakland Airport</option>
   <option value="sjc">San Jose Airport</option>
 </select>

<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Examples:
San Francisco Airport /  San Jose, CA
Oakland Airport / Berkeley, CA

Comment: Ignore your form for now.  Do you know how to pass variables to the api and get something back?

Comment: I've got these two different scripts (links above) working just fine locally as they were intended.

Comment: Can you show us your code, including sample city and airport locations that you're trying to use.

Comment: I added the form "basics" to my original post.  Just trying to send these two pieces of data to the API and get something like what they have here:  

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions

Comment: I found this script which is working with one input field.  I just don't know JS enough to try adding a 2nd field to replace the predefined destination of 'Dublin' on this one.  

http://jsfiddle.net/zufnmkgg/

Answer (score 0):

[Using this script](http://jsfiddle.net/zufnmkgg/) I was able to submit both origin and destination using a standard form after making just a little tweak of the JS, which seemed so straight-forward even I could do it.

I simply added a new form input called address2; added the var in the JS and replaced the latitude numbers with address2.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
var address = $('#address').val();
var address2 = $('#address2').val();
var request = {
    origin: address,
    destination: address2,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
```